# ESP8266 - Setting Wifi Credentials programmatically and then checking they are valid, and then change them if they are not (without reset)

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I have an NodeMCU chip that needs to connect to my home wifi and post an http request. I use the chip in **WIFI_STA_AP** mode as I need the chip to both accept requests via http and issue requests by http.

I do not want to hard-code my home's SSID/Password into the chip, so I have written some code that places the ESP (NodeMCU) into AP mode, receives the SSID/Pass via an http request and saves it on EEPROM.

This works great.

In the code below, **onTestWifi()** is called when I call **http://192.168.4.1/test_wifi?wifi_ssid=mySsid&wifi_password=myPassword**. The ssid and password are provided to the **WiFi.begin()** function. However, if I accidentally type in the wrong password and use it in **WiFi.begin()**, the connection will always fail until reset the chip and then insert the correct password.

What am I missing? Is it possible to change the ESP's wifi credentials programmatically, without having to reset the chip? Resetting the chip causes the client (in the case, an iPhone app) to disconnect from the chip and this breaks the entire program flow.

Here's the experimentation code I am using:

````
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

ESP8266WebServer server(80);
ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Starting...");
  WiFi.persistent(false);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  WiFi.softAP("APSSID");
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.softAPIP();
  server.on("/test_wifi", onTestWifi);
  server.begin();
  yield();
}

void onTestWifi()
{
  char ssid[30] = "";
  char password[30] = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < server.args(); i++)
  {
    String n = server.argName(i);
    String v = server.arg(i);
    if (n == "wifi_ssid")
      v.toCharArray(ssid, 30);
    else if (n == "wifi_password")
      v.toCharArray(password, 30);
    yield();
  }
  Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
  Serial.print(ssid);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(password);
  delay(100);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  yield();
  int counter = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && counter < 10)
  { // Wait for the Wi-Fi to connect
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(++counter);
    Serial.print(' ');
  }

  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  { // Failed to connect.
    Serial.println("Connection failed!");

  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Connection succeeded!");
  }
  yield();
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}```
````

Comment: the esp8266 stores the ssid and password by itself in flash. it uses it to automatically connect after reset or power-up. the esp8266 doesn't have EEPROM.

Comment: @Juraj well, EEPROM.get and EEPROM.put work just fine, so I would check your information :) ... check https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/25945/how-to-read-and-write-eeprom-in-esp8266 regarding saving of the ssid/password to flash - so what?  how does that pertain to my question?  thanks.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel, use the WiFiManager library. and yes the wrong password makes the esp8266 behave wrong

Comment: @Juraj "yes the wrong password makes the esp8266 behave wrong" what does this mean? Regarding WiFiManager - If I wanted to use that library I would have. That is not helpful.

Comment: tthen at least look how it works. the answers are there

Comment: @Juraj I did look at it.  I did not see any reference to WifiManager being able to handle my scenario of correcting a wrong password without having to reset the chip. If you know different, I would appreciate pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: the AP is still running and you can enter the SSID and password again? try to set invalid SSID. after that you will be able to connect to the right SSID with the correct password

Comment: @Juraj OK so that was actually a good idea but it turns out I didn't need it because figured it out. Had to add WiFi.disconnect(true). Gosh this was annoying.  Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I figured it out. Had to add the line **WiFi.disconnect(true)** in the *onTestWifi()* function. Apparently it disconnects from the network and erases the credentials. This stuff is very poorly documented and I wasted days on it. 
I hope someone finds it useful.

```
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

ESP8266WebServer server(80);
ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Starting...");
  WiFi.persistent(false);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  WiFi.softAP("APSSID");
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.softAPIP();
  server.on("/test_wifi", onTestWifi);
  server.begin();
  yield();
}

void onTestWifi()
{
  char ssid[30] = "";
  char password[30] = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < server.args(); i++)
  {
    String n = server.argName(i);
    String v = server.arg(i);
    if (n == "wifi_ssid")
      v.toCharArray(ssid, 30);
    else if (n == "wifi_password")
      v.toCharArray(password, 30);
    yield();
  }
  Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
  Serial.print(ssid);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(password);
  delay(100);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  yield();
  int counter = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && counter < 10)
  { // Wait for the Wi-Fi to connect
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(++counter);
    Serial.print(' ');
  }

  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  { // Failed to connect.
    Serial.println("Connection failed!");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Connection succeeded!");
  }
  WiFi.disconnect(true); // <--- Added this line
  yield();
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/readme.html

Comment: May need to add #include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h> at the top of the file?